# Google Admob is Not working Xcode 7.2 using objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, xcode7.2

In ViewController.h my code is

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class GADBannerView;
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet GADBannerView *addView;
@end
```

And ViewController.m File my code is

```
@import GoogleMobileAds;
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.addView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-9210017787755331/6998637808";
    self.addView.rootViewController = self;
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
        request.testDevices = @[
                            @"2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9a"  // Eric's iPod Touch
                            ];
    [self.addView loadRequest:request];
}
```

And Finally I have Disabled Bitcode. And Added ATS(Application Transport layer Security Settings ) into plist file
Anybody Please tell me what the problem is happening and how can i overcome the problem. 
Error Log is here

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setAdUnitID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f88bb51e090'
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that your bannerView has assigned in the storyboard the GADBannerView class.

You can select your banner view in the storyboard and go to custom class section and assigne GADBannerView in the class option.

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems OK but if your getting this error it means that your `addView` variable doesn't have a `adUnitId` property which means it's not behave like `GADBannerView`.

In Google's [example](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start?hl=en) everything happens in .m file. In your code some AdMob imports in .h file and some in .m file. The issue might be related with the importing the header in wrong place. Try to do it like exactly as Google's.

Comment: Hey  I have downloaded a Project From Google And previously i have added GooGle Admob Several Project . Here i have imported all  exactly same like Google Example Code using Xcode 7.2 and finally getting this error. Yesterday i straggled almost 5 hours and still trying to figure it out.